# Download file that requires clicking "download button" from command line

Tags: python, bash, selenium, curl, wget

I am wanting to automate the download of file from https://eoddata.com/download.aspx?e=FOREX. I have an account with them. The usual process involves logging in to the portal, then choosing the options as shown below & clicking the download button to download the file

[image]

The challenge is to repeat this manual process for different dates which gets cumbersome & taxing after a while. I don't mind the choice of tooling. It could be curl, wget or anything else.

Please could I request help with this.

**CODE -**

```
curl -o output_here.txt "https://<username>:<password>@www.eoddata.com/data/filedownload.aspx?e=FOREX&sd=20210722&ed=20210722&d=4&k=gi2bpin4xa&o=d&ea=1&p=0"
```

**OUTPUT -**

cat output_here.txt

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/data/filedownload.aspx?e=FOREX&amp;sd=20210722&amp;ed=20210722&amp;d=4&amp;k=gi2bpin4xa&amp;o=d&amp;ea=1&amp;p=0&amp;AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Comment: where is your code? I don't see it therefore I can't really help with any issues you are facing with your code, nor can anyone else

Comment: Apologies. . Have added code now

Comment: The next step is to follow the redirect.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice added '-L' option to curl to follow redirects. The output file is still empty

Comment: I just went to the website, its request headers look kinda complicated. I don't know if you could achieve what you want easily using curl. I would suggest using Selenium instead
(https://www.selenium.dev/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a selenium program to achieve this. Thanks to everyone for helping.